# What is the story behind / are the circumstances surrounding the conception of Bastet by Ra and Isis?

Tags: egyptian

Wikipedia lists them both as parents but gives no detail as to how it came about to be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the question not explicit? I have zero information on how Ra & Isis came to conceive Bastet and would like to know as luch as possible about that story but neither Wikipedia nor Google  gave me an answer.

Comment: Hans, to be more blunt than the Bot was, the Questions as it stands equates to something like "will you do all the work for me?" Other than a tenuous reference to Wikipedia, what research did you do and where did that leave you?